# How to get more current from laptop usb 3 port

Tags: current, amplifier, usb

did someone know about a prodact that i can connect to my usb and get up to 2A from my laptop?

Comment: Is your laptop set up to be able to give 2A out of a USB? 10W is a lot of power out of USB connection, when it's a battery powered device, so according to USB standard is allowed to max out at 100mA (0.5W)

Answer (score 2):

USB 3.0 standard says it can provide up to 4.5W (0.9A@5V) of current, with dedicated downstream charging USB 3.0 ports providing maximum 1500mA (7.5W). 5V/2A is simply not possible. The internal circuitry is not designed to supply that much current either.

Further reading/sources:
https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2020-what-are-the-maximum-power-output-and-data-transfer-rates-for-the-usb-standards
https://superuser.com/questions/1460313/what-is-the-maximum-power-supplied-by-a-usb-3-0-port